# Get the result from the first table even if no match is found in the second table - MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, left-join

I have two tables whose strcuture is as follows

```
Table name = counter
ref_id INT NOT NULL
count INT NOT NULL
```

---

```
Table name = favs
disqus_id VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
user_id INT NOT NULL
dormant VAHCHAR(10) NOT NULL
```

I run this query => `SELECT count, dormant FROM counter AS c LEFT JOIN favs AS f ON c.ref_id = f.disqus_id WHERE ref_id = 'post_5' AND user_id = '1'.`

But it returns no rows, if a match is not found in the second table `favs`. What i want is that it should return both the columns if result found, else return both columns with second one being `NULL`

How do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the the condition for the user on the `ON` clause

```
SELECT c.count, f.dormant 
FROM   counter AS c 
       LEFT JOIN favs AS f 
          ON c.ref_id = f.disqus_id  AND f.user_id = '1'
WHERE  c.ref_id = 'post_5'
```

or if still doens't work, move both:

```
SELECT c.count, f.dormant 
FROM   counter AS c 
       LEFT JOIN favs AS f 
          ON c.ref_id = f.disqus_id  AND 
             f.user_id = '1' AND
             c.ref_id = 'post_5'
```